# Как включить однооконный режим в lazarus?

Tags: ide, lazarus

Среда разработки Lazarus открывается в нескольких отдельных окнах: редактор кода, инспектор объектов, форма и верхняя панель инструментов. Как включить однооконный режим?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что вы имеете ввиду? (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете скачать Lazarus по этой ссылке там как раз интерфейс как в Visual Studio или последних версиях Delphi

https://www.getlazarus.org/

Установленный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.lazarus-ide.org/ я скачивал последнюю версию с официального сайта

Comment: @Олег Так нужно эту скачивать, в официальной насколько я помню нет "однооконого интерфейса".